# SQL Server query to find the total price of all the products by order

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Orders with `(id,orderCode,productId,quantity,color,size)`
where I can have entries like:

```
1,O20100812,163,2,BLUE,Medium
1,O20100812,163,3,BLUE,Larger
1,O20100812,145,4,RED,Large etc
1,O20100815,134,5,RED,Large etc
1,O20100815,143,2,BLACK,Large etc
1,O20100815,112,8,BLACK,Large etc
```

And another table Products with `(id,name,price)`

What I want is to find the total price of all the products in the order with orderCode 020100812. Should I DISTINCT select the order code and then SUM the quantity while JOINing the products table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why you need distinct?

```
Select SUM(o.Quantity * Price) TotalPrice
FROM Orders o JOIN Products p ON (o.ProductId = p.Id)
WHERE OrderCode = '020100812'
```

For all orders you can use the following query:

```
Select OrderCode, SUM(o.Quantity * Price) TotalPrice
FROM Orders o JOIN Products p ON (o.ProductId = p.Id)
Group by OrderCode
```

Comment: I think I need DISTINCT cause I can have multiple O20100812 and multiple O20100813 and multiple O20100816 etc

Comment: No you don't need to specify distinct. @Michael's answer is correct.

Comment: But I need to show in a html table the orderCode and the total price of the order. With WHERE I'll show only the 020100812. Should I make a query for each order?

Comment: No, you should `GROUP BY OrderCode` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

No, `GROUP BY` and then you can use `SUM` to aggregate across the group, e.g.

```
select  O.id, O.ordercode, sum(P.price * O.quantity) as total
  from  orders O
  join  products P on P.id = O.productid
group by O.id, O.ordercode
```

which will show you the total price for each order code within each order - if you wanted all order codes across all orders you'd need

```
select  O.ordercode, sum(P.price * O.quantity) as total
  from  orders O
  join  products P on P.id = O.productid
group by O.ordercode
```

i.e. don't group in the order ID.

(I'm guessing that O20100812 was just an example and you actually want this for all order codes?)

Comment: It was confirmed in a comment of the other answer that yes, it is wanted for each order, not just O20100812.

Comment: @Cœur and that's what my answer does, I think? Obviously it was years ago I wrote it.

Comment: Yes, that's what your answer is doing. I was just confirming that your interrogation was a correct guess.